# Fingerprint reader stopped working Lenovo E430

Tags: lenovo, fingerprint-reader

I had fingerprint-gui set up and working nicely, used it for login and authenticating root stuff. Now suddenly it stopped working. It does not show the "Enroll your finger" prompt.

I reinstalled fingerprint-gui and it does not recognize my fingerprint reader.
It just shows "No devices found". But in the menu underneath it shows " Upek (0x147e) Biometric Touchstrip / Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor (0x1002) "

I don't understand because until now it was running just fine.

Ubuntu 12.04, Unity

UPDATE: WORKS NOW - Probably after an update

Comment: It works now.. Probably an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing happened for me after yesterdays update. It just stoped working. I have a Lenovo T420 and Ubuntu 13.04 x64.

Since it was an fingerprint-gui update I'm guessing that this is not an Ubuntu issue but it's worth a try asking :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.